# Semistability and normal crossing divisors

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a complex family of curves beetween singular surface $X$ and a smooth curve $Y,$ where $X$ has singularities on singular fibers of the family (rational double points as singularities). Let $S\subset Y$ be a discriminant locus of the family and $T=f^{*}S$ a normal crossing divisor. Let $D\subset X$ be a divisor on $X$ without vertical components. Is it possible to do in the same time process of semistability(fibers are reduced normal crossing divisors) of the family $f:X\rightarrow Y$ (by taking a ramified covering $Y'$ and then the desingularization $W$ of $X\times Y'$) obteining the family $f':W\rightarrow Y'$ and to assume that pull-back of the divisor $T+D$ on $W$ is normal crossing divisor ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by "the same time". Given any smooth surface any any divisor, we can always blow up enough times to make that divisor normal crossings. (I think this is discussed in Hartshorne?) So after disingularization, if you blow up a few more times, it will still be a designularization, but with $T+D$ normal crossings.

If we are are required to take the minimal disingularization of $X \times_Y Y'$, the answer is no. Consider a case when a fiber has one smooth component and one component of multiplicity 2. Then to get semistable reduction you must pull back by a covering of order a multiple of 2. Now $T$ should contain this fiber  as it is singular. Let $D$ be a section intersecting the smooth locus. When we pull back by a ramified covering the intersection between teh omponent of $T$ and $D$ will no longer be a normal crossing.

Comment: in the same time I meant to get semistable family and to have the pullback of  the divisor with normal crossings.

Comment: Or, after semistability process if we do blowups to get the normal crossing divisor do we endenger the semistability of the family?

Comment: @mne88 The blowups are just blowups of smooth points. So one just has to check that the blowup of a smooth point preserves semistability, which is clear.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this last claim, that blow ups of smooth point preserves smistability?

Comment: @mne88 Sorry this is wrong. The result I am thinking of only shows the fiber remains a simple crossings divisor - it does not necessarily remain reduced.

Comment: @mne88 Still the statement is correct, but it requires more. What you want is one form of the semistable reduction theorem for curves.  For instance you may take a ramified covering so that $D$ becomes a union of sections. Then each fiber is a curve with marked points, and your desired statement is almost the same as the properness of the Deligne-Mumford moduli space of curves with marked points - the difference being that you want the semistable family to map to your original family, but you have no condition on genus $0$ curves in the special fiber.

Comment: @mne88  I think this can be obtained by just taking a proof of the Deligne-Mumford statement and skipping the steps where you blow down curves, but I haven't found a suitable reference.

Comment: Tnx. Do you have the exact reference for Deligne Mumford statement? I tried to find but I did not find the one that can be similar to my problem.

Comment: @mne88 I'm not sure. Maybe more relevant is the proof of the stable reduction theorem, as described here https://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.1048.pdf page 18 and 19. Following the same steps but also keeping track of the divisor $D$ (including it in the log resolution, noting it in the local model when your resolve singularities) might get you what you want.

Comment: tnx a lot of...